# Joomla: How to include a second article content area on front page

Tags: joomla

Joomla newbie here.  I understand how to build a "front page" using a menu item with the Front Page Blog Layout so that article content appears on the front page.  But I'd also like to include article content (from another section or category) in the left column area. How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any sort of module that displays content--you can find many content showcase galleries in the extension directory

Comment: I discovered that the built-in "News Flash" module does this.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking out [this](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/articlesanywhere) brand new extension: